# Word choice: of/in

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> Every table of the restaurant that he owns/of all the restaurants.

or

> Every table in the restaurant he owns?

Any other correct solution?

Comment: Are you asking a question or stating a fact?

Comment: @SovereignSun: Neither. Whatever preposition is included, OP's text is simply a ***noun phrase***, not a "sentence" which could be classified as either a question or an assertion.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I guessed that the OP can't write correctly. I mean he must have meant **"Does he own every table in the restaurant?"** or **"He owns every table in the restaurant."**

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE: ***of*** would be unlikely (though not actually "ungrammatical") in your specific context, but ***at*** is a perfectly natural alternative to ***in*** here. It's really a stylistic choice whether to go for the "locational" preposition *(at)* or the "metaphorical container" version *(in)*. My guess is that for tables/restaurants, ***in*** would be more common, but that might not be true for all combinations of items and their normal/fixed locations.

Comment: @SovereignSun Which fact? Word choice...or...

Comment: " I guessed that the OP can't write correctly." Oh, that's nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use *in* because the tables are IN the restaurant. They're physically located inside of it.

And they're not of or ABOUT the restaurant. The preposition *of* is somewhat similar in meaning to the preposition *about*. That's why you have to use *in*.

Comment: My hesitation comes from "one table among the quantity of tables". One out of all the tables. So there's no way to change the sentence to use "of" if I understand well? "A table in all the restaurants".

Comment: In this situation, no. "tables of the restaurant" just sounds wrong. "one out of a quantity" is a completely different phrase.

Comment: OK, thank you. It's a different way to consider it in English than in some other languages. Different languages, different visions. The English emphasizes the place apparently, not the total amount.